# Find Intersection of two tangent of arc

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, tangent-line

I have one arc with given data :

1. centre point
2. arc  start point angle
3. arc end point angle
4. arc start point radius
5. arc end point radius (both radius are almost same)

now i want to find intersection point of two tangent of this arc. any help please?

Comment: Which tangents ?

Comment: Please add aditional information, because now we don't know what two tangents do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are start and end point angles, then the intersection of the two tangents at the endpoints corresponds to an angle of $(\alpha+\beta)/2$ and to a distance from center $d=R/\cos(\beta-\alpha)$, where $R$ is the radius.